# can't install bower package because there seems to be a duplicate

Tags: bower

I wanted to install the backbone.routefilter plugin via Bower. It looks like there are 2 projects with that same name. http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/#!/search/routefilter.

When I try to bower install backbone.routefilter#0.2.0 it tries to install 0.2.0 version from wanderer I want the latest from boazsender. Is there anyway to tell bower which repo to use?

Answer (score 0):

That one seems to be wrongly registered. Use the correct one instead:

`bower install backbone.routefilter`

Comment: the repo owned by boazsender (the one thats wrongly registered as you put it) is the plugin thats maintained and further updated. Hence thats the one I want to be able to use.

Comment: @JonathanW seems like a bug in Bower. It shouldn't let packages with that name be registered. Open a ticket about it. To fix the current situation, you can comment here about getting the name changed: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/120